# How to return two specific columns from database using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, webforms

I have table called Asset. It has lot of columns. I only want to select two of them and use them separately. 
Both of these columns are strings.

Linq query :

```
public static List<string> GetAssetIdsWithNames()
{
    using (var db = DbManager.Get())
    {
        var result = db.Assets.SelectMany(i=> new[] { i.AssetName, i.AssetId }).Distinct().ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Where I want to use them :

```
            var assetList = AssetManager.GetAssetIdsWithNames();
            //CURRENCYBOX IS A DROPDOWN            
            CurrencyBox.DataSource = assetList;
            CurrencyBox.DataBind();

            foreach (var item in assetList)
            {
                CurrencyBox.DataValueField = //asset id goes here
                CurrencyBox.DataTextField =//asset name goes here


                break;
            }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Izzy I get List<string>. I can not use AssetId and AssetName separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the anonymous type outside of the local scope.

Anonymous types can only be returned as `Object` outside their local scope and their properties inspected via reflection.

So in this scenario, you are likely better off to use a typed data contract and map from your Asset entity instead and then access it from your calling method.

Your use of `SelectMany` seems odd too, you probably are after `Select` instead.

```
public class AssetDto
{
  public string Name { get;set; }
  public string Id { get; set; }
}

public static List<AssetDto> GetAssetIdsWithNames()
{
    using (var db = DbManager.Get())
    {
        var result = db.Assets.Select(i=> new AssetDto { Name = i.AssetName, Id = i.AssetId }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use named value tuples for that so you don't need to create an extra class

```
public static List<(string Name, int Id)> GetAssetWithIds()
{
    using (var db = DbManager.Get())
    {
        var result = db.Assets
            .Select(a => new { a.AssetName, a.AssetId })
            .Distinct().AsEnumerable()
            .Select(a => (a.AssetName, a.AssetId))
            .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

You will need to add `System.ValueTuple`